# How do I determine future balance owed on a mortgage based on amortization?

Tags: mortgage, financial-literacy, amortization

A family buys a house worth 326000.They pay 110 000 down and then take out a 5-year mortgage for the balance at j2 = 6.5% to be amortized over 20 years. Payments will be paid monthly. Determine the outstanding balance at the end of 5 years and the owner’s equity at that time.

I'm unsure of how to solve this question.

EDIT: Hi, this is not a homework question by the way. I came across it in my studies for my final exam and it didn't make sense to me, however, I wish to continue to have the ability to do financial math in the future, even if I am not in the course, so I wanted clarification.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @duff - feels like it - in particular given the odd dual nature.  @Justin - suggest edit to have only one question here.

Comment: This is two questions, and you won't be clogging up the area by asking two questions.   The answers below are related to the mortgage schedule so I'm editing out the bond question.   Please repost as a separate question and you'll likely get better answers to the bond portion of your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent mortgage calculator that I use:

[RateSupermarket.ca Mortgage Calculator](http://www.ratesupermarket.ca/mortgage/rate_calculator/)

Enter in the property value, down payment, interest and the amortization period and go at the bottom and you can see the amortization schedule. You can read off how much the balance is at the end of 5 years and the owner's equity at the time.

No thoughts on the bond schedule. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Having recently taken an Engineering Management course, my professor has made available to us/public an [excel spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BxAG9t9MeGqLYjEzN2JjYjAtZjA2Mi00MGJiLTgxODUtNTdhZTQwZjUzMmJk&authkey=CI7c4s4M&hl=en) that calculates Home Mortgage payments with detailed notes.  It contains calculations for Fixed rate, ARM (Adjustable Rate Mortgage), Interest only, and Negative Amortization Mortgages.  The purpose of the spreadsheet is to show how to calculate each month how much the individual owes, how much interest and principal is paid with each type of mortgage.  Click on the link and you'll have access to the same.

Answer (score 0):

A financial calculator answers this pretty easily.
PV (present value) = $216,000 (I don't care what the house costs, only what the mortgage is.

%i (percent interest per period = .065/12

N (number of periods) = 240

FV (future value) = 0 amortized over the 20 years.

PMT (payment) = $905.89 this is the payment, but not the answer.

We need to enter 60 as N, and calculate FV = $162,262.

The principal was paid down by 216000-162262 or $53,738. Add the $110,000 down payment, and the total the buyer has paid in is $163,738. This is his equity, but only if the value of the house has remained constant. The house may have gone up or down in value, of course.